# Designer - Tab order

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, tabs

I use to set Tab ordering through Visual Studio 2008 (winform). However, I couldn't find this option either in 2010/2012(WPF) . Is there any known rational behind this omission?

Following is a screenshot, which I was referring under VS 2008 version.

[image: VS menu] 
[image: this is how the designer looks after setting tab order]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tool is not currently available for WPF. 
I guess we need to play with [KeyboardNavigation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class and/or [TabIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.tabindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property, either in XAML or in Properties window.

I'm not sure why this feature is not included. According to [someone from Microsoft](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/38a7953e-6cff-40a6-abc9-8fa0f2a6f9a9/changing-tab-order-on-wpf-form-in-vs2010?forum=vswpfdesigner), they simply didn't have time to include this feature in the 2010 release. Another [reply](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/84e47335-a664-4d28-883b-b68d462142e3/tab-order?forum=vswpfdesigner) from the same person gave the impression that this feature might be included in future releases. (Both links are 5 years old).

However, the 2012, 2013, & 2015 versions still don't have this feature.

Comment: Question was to know the reason on why this is ignored in further versions. Sorry If my questions wasn't clear to you.

Comment: Edited my answer to better reflect the updated question. Though I'm not sure why the more recent VS versions still don't have the feature.

Comment: That sounds strange to me since this is not a new feature and something they had it in the past. So the justification doesn't seems worth for me. Anyways. Thanks for reference.